# Obtain E(W) and assuming independence obtain V(W) - Random Variable

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

I am actually lost on how to get the answer for this question:

Consider the random variables X~N (0,2) and Y~N (1,4). Define the random variable W= 4X-6Y+3. Obtain E(W), and assuming independence obtain V(W).

What does the X~N symbolize? Is it the range in the normal distribution curve?

Hope you can help me with this
Thank you,

Comment: Read $\sim$ as "distributed as" and "N" as short for "normal". The two numbers following are the mean and variance parameters. See the Wikipedia article on the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution); the arguments in the parentheses are defined in the sidebar on the right there.

Comment: Can you add the `self-study` tag as your question clearly pertains to this category?

Answer (score 0):

The symbol $X\sim \mathit{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ symbolizes that $X$ has normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$.

In general in statistics the symbol $X \sim \mathit{P}(\theta_1,\theta_2,...,\theta_n)$ says that $X$ has the distribution defined by $\mathit{P}$ with parameters $\theta_1,\theta_2,...,\theta_n$.

Comment: Okay, noted on this. Would you mind if you help me get through with this problem? So, (0,2) is the mean and variance of X while (1,4) is the mean and variance of Y. What does it mean when it says assuming independence of E(W) and V(W)? Thank you.

Comment: For the expected value E(x) calculation you don't need to asume independence.

Comment: For the variance V(W) calculation if you assume independence you can drop out the term of covariance and it takes the form of a sum. I recommend you to read the properties item in the Wikipedia 's articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Comment: "assuming independence" means assume X and Y are independent.  That is not spelled out with explicit clarity, but is clearly what is meant.